# clang error: non-const lvalue reference cannot bind to incompatible temporary

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clang

I have a piece of code that works fine with MSVC but fails to compile with clang++

```
void MyCass::someMethod()
{
   std::wstring key(...);
   auto& refInstance = m_map.find(key); // error here
}
```

where m_map is defined as

```
std::map<const std::wstring, std::shared_ptr<IInterface>> m_map;
```

and clang complains

```
non-const lvalue reference cannot bind to incompatible temporary
```

I somewhat understand that a temporary is being created but not sure how to go fixing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

rvalues cannot bind to non-const references. MSVC has an "extension that allows that. To be standards compliant, you need

```
const auto& refInstance = m_map.find(key);
```

But this returns an iterator. It is unusual to use references to iterators. Values are fine:

```
auto refInstance = m_map.find(key);
```

Comment: legacy code :). The reference is then later being compared with m_map.end() end to see if the key was not found.

Comment: @randomThought Yes, but you don't need references for that.